# DuckDuckGo is strangely behaving like a browser hijacker. I've already tried your tips. Pls advise

Tags: malware, persistent

I think I've tried everything:  made Disconnect my default search engine (instead of Duk); unchecked all other search engines; made Tor my default browser (instead of Mozilla); untrusted Duk & trusted Disconnect in Noscript; cleared the cache in Tor (& in Internet Explorer- which has long been TURNED OFF - & in Moz FF); made Tor my default browser (instead of Mozilla), closed & opened it. Still, every time I search for an item with the sole remaining search engine in TOR- Disconnect- I get -Tor has prevented a redirect to DuckDuckGo. What am I missing?

Comment: Disconnect redirects to DuckDuckGo. It's Disconnect redirecting you, not DuckDuckGo "hijacking", nothing malicious.